# Introduction of Fake Reviews

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred

I occasionally review first posts on Stack Overflow or Super User (if non are present here on Web Applications harhar). There a fake post procedure is in place to check on review quality.

Can we have such a system here on Web Applications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy enough to enable, but... We won't enable it *now* and probably won't enable it *soon* on Web Apps. There just isn't enough review traffic to warrant it here.

To elaborate a bit: review audits are most useful on sites that have so much review traffic that it can't be effectively overseen by other users on the site (anyone can see anyone else's reviews via user profiles, 10K users and mods can see everyone's review history via the History tab on each queue, and mods have more extensive statistics as well to help them identify folks behaving badly).

Also, audits themselves are created from a pool of recent posts matching specific criteria on the site; these pools would be extremely small on WA. This could be fixed, but scaling audits down to sites where the pool of active reviewers can be counted on one hand isn't really a priority.

If you're concerned about what action to take for a given review item, don't hesitate to ask about it here on meta; if you're concerned about the behavior of another reviewer, don't hesitate to flag a post for moderator attention and ask them to have a look (if it's a behavior common to multiple reviewers, you could also raise that discussion here on meta).

Comment: Clearly stated, thanks.